# Java sql query works manually but doesn't execute in java code

Tags: java, sql

So I want to add something to database, but it doesn't work, it won't do `this.statement.executeUpdate(sqlQuery);`. If I print out the `sqlQuery` and call it in phpMyAdmin it works.

I have several DB iterations, similar to this, working perfectly fine, but this one randomly doesn't.

SQL QUERY:

```
INSERT INTO tvshows (title, plot, poster, imdb_rating, imdb_url, imdb_id, release_date) 
VALUES('The Office', 'A mockumentary on a group of typical office workers, where the workday consists of ego clashes, inappropriate behavior, and tedium. Based on the hit BBC series.', 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTgzNjAzMDE0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTEyMzM3OA@@._V1._SY317_CR9,0,214,317_.jpg', '8.9', 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0386676/', 'tt0386676', '2005-06-11')
```

Code:

```
public boolean insert_tvShow(TvShow tvShow) {

    boolean success = false;
    String plot = tvShow.getPlot();
    plot = plot.replaceAll("'", "''");

    try {
        this.statement = this.connection.createStatement();
        String sqlQuery = String.format("INSERT INTO tvshows (title, plot, poster, imdb_rating, imdb_url, imdb_id, release_date) " +
                                        "VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
                                        tvShow.getTitle(),
                                        plot,
                                        tvShow.getPoster(),
                                        tvShow.getImdb_Rating(),
                                        tvShow.getImdb_url(),
                                        tvShow.getImdb_id(),
                                        tvShow.getReleaseDate());
        System.out.println(sqlQuery);
        this.statement.executeUpdate(sqlQuery);
        success = true;
    } catch(Exception e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }

    return success;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Ok I use PreparedStatement from now on.
But I still won't get the code to execute. Since I get no errors, I have no way of knowing. Probably one cause is my release_date, so I try to get it work without it first.
"ps.executeUpdate();" is where the code reaches.

```
public boolean insert_tvShow(TvShow tvShow) {

    boolean success = false;
    java.util.Date myDate = new java.util.Date("10/10/2009");

    try {
        String sqlString = "INSERT INTO tvshows (title, plot, poster, imdb_rating, imdb_url, imdb_id, release_date) " +
                            "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sqlString);
        ps.setString(1, tvShow.getTitle()); 
        ps.setString(2, tvShow.getPlot()); 
        ps.setString(3, tvShow.getPoster()); 
        ps.setDouble(4, tvShow.getImdb_Rating()); 
        ps.setString(5, tvShow.getImdb_url()); 
        ps.setString(6, tvShow.getImdb_id());
        ps.setDate(7, new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime()));
        ps.executeUpdate();
        connection.commit();
        success = true;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //TODO logging
    } finally {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: [SQL-Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) hooray!

Comment: Jeeez, I never thought finding a _Java_ SQL injection prone code would be so refreshing after finding a whole lot of _PHP_ ones... Seriously, even valid strings like "Bob's tales" would break this... (not to mention Bob's _tables_ :) )

Comment: Hello [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)! Use a `PreparedStatement` and your (and our) worries are gone.

Comment: @jlordo I thougth exactly the same, when saw _Bobby_ comment this... I usually mention **thank god it doesn't work** on similar questions... But hey, is this really prone to SQL injection? `'` is replaced to `''`

Comment: @Bobby Tables... is that you?

Comment: @KevinBrydon: Nope, [Bobby Tables is that other Bobby](http://stackoverflow.com/users/334849/littlebobbytables).

Comment: If you're wondering what the fuzz is about, try running that function with a plot which looks like this: `This is a very cool plot with a twist \'; DROP TABLE tvshows; --`

Comment: Despite the SQL injection vulnerability, nobody seems to actually be answering the OP's question.

Comment: @Bobby the plot is escaped, but all other fields are not... (`plot = plot.replaceAll("'", "''");`)

Comment: @ppeterka: That's why I escape that apostrophe.

Comment: @Bobby dumb me... I could swear, that backslash wasn't there on my screen...

Comment: @ppeterka: Looks like you're accusing me of... \*puts.sunglasses.on\*...injecting it. *YEEEEEAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHH*

Comment: @Bobby touché, sir! Well palyed! I think I found a perfect situation to use the word "flummoxed", as in "I'm totally flummoxed"...

Comment: @Bobby Also, what you did is now __escaping__ _escaping_ by **escaping**, I think...

Comment: @ppeterka: It's nice that you taught me a new word (flummox) and *then* show me what it means to be flummoxed. And yes, I think that sentence is correctly escaped...or such....

Comment: @user1335163 why did you collapse myDate from object form to a number, then build a new object out of the number?  I doubt that is causing things to fail, but it is very confusing.

Comment: "Since I get no errors ... `catch (Exception ex) { // TODO: Logging }`" That's a joke, right?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is very prone to SQL injection attack.
If someone entered a TV show called '; drop table tvshows;' for example, what do you think could happen?

Use parameters:

```
    PreparedStatement ps = this.connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tvshows (title, plot, poster, imdb_rating, imdb_url, imdb_id, release_date) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    ps.setString(1, tvShow.getTitle());
    ps.setString(2, tvSHow.getPlot();
    //etc...

    ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: I suppose strictly speaking it doesn't, but the code I gave would also solve the OP's stated problem as well as the SQL injection problem.

Answer (score 2):

Don't ever ever ever ever ever do this:

```
 String sqlQuery = String.format("INSERT INTO tvshows (title, plot, poster, imdb_rating, imdb_url, imdb_id, release_date) " +
                                        "VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
                                        tvShow.getTitle(),
                                        plot,
                                        tvShow.getPoster(),
                                        tvShow.getImdb_Rating(),
                                        tvShow.getImdb_url(),
                                        tvShow.getImdb_id(),
                                        tvShow.getReleaseDate());
```

Replace it with this:

```
    PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tvshows (title, plot, poster, imdb_rating, imdb_url, imdb_id, release_date) " +
                                                "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
statement.setString(1,"title");  
//rest of setters here  
statement.execute();  
conn.commit();
```

Comment: Personally, I'd suggest the SET-Syntax for better readability.

Comment: @Bobby am I not using the set syntax?  Or is this something else I am unaware of?

Comment: I meant this: `INSERT INTO tvshows SET title = ?, plot = ?, poster = ?, ...`

Comment: @Bobby ah, TIL about set syntax

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the problem is the release date.  Databases are fussy about how they accept dates and times.  You can't just shove a string that looks like a date into a SQL query.

I recommend going through the appropriate JDBC method, which is PreparedStatement.setTimestamp, which gives the JDBC driver the ability to convert a Java object representing the date into a structure the database will accept.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp(int, java.sql.Timestamp)

And after you've read about the PrepatedStatement interface, might I suggest you research SQL injection?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Since some of the comments mentioned Bobby Tables, here is some information about Little Bobby.

http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Hey, this is a nice one, without actually seeing any relevant error messages and whatnot... And this could very well be the immediate problem OP struggles with...

Comment: @user1335163 OP, you need to check if Date is really the correct type.  You may need to research it with your database.  There is Date, Time and Timestamp, which are different and may map to particular SQL types in your underlying RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `PreparedStatement`:

```java
    String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tvshows (title, plot, poster, imdb_rating, imdb_url, imdb_id, release_date) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    final PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, tvShow.getTitle());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, plot);
    preparedStatement.setString(3, tvShow.getPoster());
    preparedStatement.setString(4, tvShow.getImdb_Rating());
    preparedStatement.setString(5, tvShow.getImdb_url());
    preparedStatement.setString(6, tvShow.getImdb_id());
    preparedStatement.setString(7, tvShow.getReleaseDate());
```

**Never build queries using a `String`**.

Queries built using a `String` a prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. They are also prone to issues with `String` escaping, like the `'` in the your example.

Comment: Actually OP has not demonstrated why it is a bad idea.  You are also not explaining why it is a bad idea for future readers.

Comment: @Woot4Moo edited to make it clear that the issue is SQL Injection and String escaping.